# what does mean unique users and getting its value for a perticular application In Fluury

Tags: php, curl, flurry

Fluury Issue : I want to know, what does mean unique users in flurry and how to get its value for a perticular application in flurry  ?
I have this api : http://api.flurry.com/appInfo/getApplication?apiAccessCode=APIACCESSCODE&apiKey=APIKEY&versionName=VERSIONNAME&country=COUNTRY.
i provided accesscode and api key since version name and country are optional, but its not getting.

please reply and please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Flurry's [Support page](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=API/Code) for more details on how to achieve this.